# How to join data from Dataframe rows into one single row

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyqgis

This should be easy (I can do it in Excel quickly enough).
I have the following Dataframe and I want to join, concatenate, aggregate the XY pairs into one string (and then add text at the start and end).

```
    Easting     Northing
0   416213.873  6507344.904
1   424283.1    6509982.331
2   428632.58   6496675.102
3   418176.907  6493257.665
4   415338.984  6501940.281
5   416213.873  6507344.904
```

I have used this line to join each XY pair.

```
df['WKT'] = df[['Easting', 'Northing']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)

    Easting     Northing    WKT
0   416213.873  6507344.904 416213.873 6507344.904
1   424283.1    6509982.331 424283.1 6509982.331
2   428632.58   6496675.102 428632.58 6496675.102
3   418176.907  6493257.665 418176.907 6493257.665
4   415338.984  6501940.281 415338.984 6501940.281
5   416213.873  6507344.904 416213.873 6507344.904
```

I experimented with .join and .agg but didn't get what I wanted. I also looked at Pivot but couldn't get that to work either.

What I want to do is get here, where all the Easting/Northing pairs are joined to form a single string with ',' between them - Then add "POLYGON((" to the front and "))" to the end.

> POLYGON((X0 Y0,X1 Y1,X2 Y2,X3 Y3,X4 Y4,X5 Y5))

In this case there are 5 points, the 6th is a duplicate of the 1st to close the box.
It won't always be a fixed number of points so I looked at iterable loops, but as the basic joining didn't work, the loop produced garbage too.

Secondary part of question referring to LineString.
The input file will be like this, but I only import the SOLE,SOLE,EOLE,EOLN:

```
Line #,Name,SOLE,SOLN,EOLE,EOLN,SOLKP,EOLKP
1,EQ23303-01001-04,421386.910,6499570.855,420145.852,6503366.914,0.000,3.994
2,EQ23303-01005-08,421410.672,6499578.623,420169.615,6503374.683,0.000,3.994
3,EQ23303-01009-12,421434.435,6499586.392,420193.377,6503382.451,0.000,3.994
4,EQ23303-01013-16,421458.197,6499594.161,420217.139,6503390.220,0.000,3.994
```

The output I am trying to get, for each line, is:

```
LINESTRING(SOLE SOLN,EOLE EOLN)
```

Simply, it's just a concatenation of the row with a space between  X and Y and a , between the XY pair.
I have another way of doing it but seeing the shapely function I wondered if there was a neater method.

Comment: quick and dirty way would be to convert your `dtype` to `str` with `df = df.astype(str)` and  use list comprehension `poly_corners = "POLYGON((" + ",".join([" ".join(values) for values in df.values.tolist()]) + "))"`

Comment: @BijayRegmi When I first tried this it gave me a space  between every digit. I removed the space from the ([ " ".join(values) and it worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html) from [shapely](/questions/tagged/shapely) :

```
#pip install shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p = Polygon([(x, y) for x, y in zip(df["Easting"], df["Northing"])])
```

Output :

```
print(type(p))
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>

print(str(p))

POLYGON ((416213.873 6507344.904, 424283.1 6509982.331, 428632.58 6496675.102, 418176.907 6493257.665, 415338.984 6501940.281, 416213.873 6507344.904))
```

[image]

Comment: @Timelss Looking at the Shapely function, it looks like I can also make a LINESTRING. I have tried to adjust your answer above using my 4 consecutive dataframe columns SOLE (Start of line Easting), SOLN, EOLE and EOLN.      l = LineString([(x, y) for x, y in zip((df["SOLE"],df["SOLN"]), (df["EOLE"], df["EOLN"]))]) but I get the message TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: Can you give an example and show a valid LineString expected output ?

Comment: I have added a second part to the question with a data snippet and valid LINESTRING.

Comment: Thanks but `LINESTRING(SOLE SOLN,EOLE EOLN)` is not a valid object. Can you construct a valid linestring with explicit values that matches the second given input ?

Comment: Sorry, poorly explained question by me. The output from each row should look like LINESTRING(421386.910 6499570.855,420145.852 6503366.914). I suspect I may need to loop through each row to create each individual LineString.